# Implement authorization in SOA

Tags: soa

I have a question abut what is the best practice/pattern to ensure proper authorization in my SOA application. I have a bunch of services that allow users access certain data (stored in DB). An example of a typical scenario is...

We have a EMPLOYEE table that has say a one to many relationship with PROJECT. So AN EMPLOYEE can have many PROJECTS. Also each employee belongs to a region. The users of the system are allowed to edit information on employee and projects. However Each user only manages data for a few regions and therefore can only modify employees and their projects that belong to a region that the user manages. So user may have access to regions A, B, C and can edit employee/project data for Region A employee but not region Z employee.

I have one service that lets you edit an employee and another to edit an project. Similarly a project has relationships to other entities, for e.g. SCHEDULE, and I have services to edit those as well.

However my problem is this -- whether an user can edit or not a project or schedule, by calling the corresponding service, is determined by which region the employee (to which these projects and schedules are related) belongs to. So for every service to modify a project or schedule or any entity in that hierarchy of data starting at employee, I am having to query the corresponding employee and enforce the region constraints. Which can become very expensive operation considering the database calls and number of joins (my real example has lot of such entities and corresponding services) I have to make on every service call. Is there a more elegant light weight solution for my scenario?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd call these requirements regular business rules rather than authorization. Authorization is usually much more generic in nature, meaning whether a user is allowed access to a specific system or is allowed to invoke a certain function (regardless of parameters).

Second, and based on a business rules view, you should take into account the consistency needs around these business rules before dividing things up into services.

Third, relating to your statement "my real example has lot of such entities and corresponding services", it usually not a good idea to have services that correspond to entities.

So, in summary, you need to redesign your service boundaries such that the rules that need to be enforced (in a highly consistent manner) are contained within a single service. One way to do that is to take different parts of a given entity and put them in different services - provided that there aren't any business rules that demand consistency across those diffe